# All characters of the c# application shown as square character in only one computer

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, encoding, user-interface

I have a .net 3.5 application written in c# and it works fine except in one windows 2003 server. In that server all characters of the application shown as square characters. i have another windows 2003 server with exactly the same regional settings but application works fine in that server. Also when i copied the square characters to an another application characters shown as normal. What can be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Is this an asp.net application?

Comment: Does that machine have the correct font's and language settings installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing a font, or a regional setting on that machine. Find out what fonts are you using in your app, and/or compare the fonts directories between the machines.

Comment: You are right, its a font problem i changed the font of the application and now characters are shown as normal, thanks.